# Google Calendar: deleting alert from recurring event invite doesn't stick

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business, notifications, calendar, events

I have various recurring events I have been invited to on Google Calendar (GSuite). Some of them are not actually meetings or I am not interested in being alerted for them, yet they come preconfigured with some alert. When I edit the event, remove the alert, save, and select to apply the change to this and future events, it seems to work fine. However if I immediately go back into the event the notification is still there like before every time. This doesn't happen for non-recurring events. Removing the alert works if you select to save the changes only for the currently selected events instead of all future events.

Is there a way to remove (or mute) these alerts short of

1. disabling all alerts on my calendar,
2. editing each one individually until the end of time, or
3. asking the creator of the event to remove the alert whenever I'm invited to an event with an alert baked in (I'm assuming that's where the alert is coming from)?